# '+=' : pointer on left; needs integral value on right

Tags: c++, c

I am confused. I can not use this on a float? Must it be a integer? I try to define that as a point but I guess I can not convert float to float *

```
//global definition
float g_posX = 0.0f;

&g_posX -= 3.03f;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You probably simply want to do this:

```
float g_posX = 0.0f;
g_posX -= 3.03f;
```

What your code tries to do is take the address of `g_posX` and subtract `3.03f` from the *address*. That does not work, for two reasons:

- The address is not an lvalue: it cannot be assigned to. Assigning to an address would be meaningless. What would it do, move the variable around in memory?
- Pointer arithmetic can only be done using integers. Fractional addresses do not exist.

Comment: It would be fun to do bit access like that: `bool* ptr = &myInteger + 0.125;`

Comment: Yeah, the thought occurred to me. And of course, if the float is not a multiple of 1/8, it should interpolate between bit values and return fractional bits, or *frits*.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to subtract from the float then just name the variable and don't take its address:

```
g_posX -= 3.03f;
```

Otherwise, `&g_posX` is an `rvalue` that you can't assign to it anything.

Answer (score 0):

well, `&g_posX` is a pointer to the float. Pointers are memory addresses and (more or less) intereger. To increase the float, simply remove the `&`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the the & before g_posX, just do the maths like

```
g_posX -= 3.03f;
```

Answer (score -1):

increment and decrement operators are only defined for integral data types, not for floating point, double, etc.

Comment: it's not true. As mentioned in many other reponses "g_posX -= 3.03f;" works just fine