# passing a float as a pointer to a matrix

Tags: c++, c

Honestly, I couldnt think of a better title for this issue because I am having 2 problems and I don't know the cause.

The first problem I have is this

```
//global declaration
float g_posX = 0.0f;
.............


//if keydown happens
g_posX += 0.03f;


&m_mtxView._41 = g_posX;
```

I get this error

```
cannot convert from 'float' to 'float *'
```

So I assume that the matrix only accepts pointers. So i change the varible to this....

```
//global declaration
float *g_posX = 0.0f;
.............


//if keydown happens
g_posX += 0.03f;


&m_mtxView._41 = &g_posX;
```

and I get this error

```
cannot convert from 'float' to 'float *'
```

which is pretty much saying that I can not declare g_posX as a pointer.

honestly, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Show us the declaration and type of m_mtxView.  However, you current code still has the same issue as your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2802418/pointer-on-left-needs-integral-value-on-right).

Comment: Why do you keep trying to take the address of everything?

Comment: What's the definition of matrix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.)**

```
m_mtxView._41 = g_posX;
```

**2.)**

```
Update: this piece of code is quite unnecessary, although it shows how to use a pointer allocated on the heap.

float* g_posX = new float; // declare a pointer to the address of a new float
*g_posX = 0.0f; // set the value of what it points to, to 0.0This
m_mtxView._41 = *g_posX; // set the value of m_mtxView._41 to the value of g_posX
delete g_posX; // free the memory that posX allocates.
```

Hint: Read "*****" as "value of" and "**&**" as "address of"

Comment: It's also hard to see how the second `float` would ever be freed.

Comment: Thanks. I get lost with the understanding of these pointers sometimes.

Comment: @Viktor: And after your update the code is such that `m_mtxView._41` points to a `float` that got deleted.

Comment: @Viktor: Yeah, sorry, my brainfart. Anyway, the whole dynamic memory thing is - pardon my French - stupid. 2) buys nothing over 1) but opportunity for errors - especially for someone who's still confused about pointers.

Comment: @sbi: Simple examples can be used as demonstrations for more complex goals.  The fact that *this* example is "useless" on its own does not mean that the concept of dynamic memory management is useless.

Comment: @sbi; might be, I just modified his code to show how he should write to make it work

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to take the address of `m_mtxView._41`? What's wrong with `m_mtxView._41 = g_posX;`?

Comment: @numerical25: I thought this happened with `&m_mtxView._41 = g_posX;` (note the `&`)?